# How to draw edge labels when there are multi edges in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a node called T in the middle that has two bidirectional nodes going from it to other 2 nodes. I want to draw the edge weight in the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiGraph()

edge_list = [("1","2", 1),
              ("3", "1", 2)]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_list)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G,seed=5)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color = 'b', node_size = 500, alpha = 1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color='w') 
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)
```

It fails at the 'nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels' saying:

```
NetworkXError: draw_networkx_edge_labels does not support multiedges.
```

The rest of the code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
for e in G.edges:
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[e[0]], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[e[1]], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0",
                                shrinkA=12, shrinkB=12,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=rrr".replace('rrr',str(0.3*e[2])
                                ),
                                ),
                )

plt.axis('off')
```

I have tried following the answer from Github by [aristaeus](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/issues/51):

```
from pyvis.network import Network
nt = Network(directed=False)
nt.from_nx(G)
nt.set_edge_smooth('dynamic')
nt.show('foo.html')
```

Unfortunately, I received:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Change the `edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')`  to `dict([((n1, n2), d['weight']) for n1, n2, d in G.edges(data=True)])`

Comment: Do you need to use a `MultiGraph`? The `DiGraph` class support bi-directional edges, you only need a `MultiGraph` if you have multiple edges between the same nodes going in the same direction.